# Change the position of local view and remote view when call establish (SINCH swift project)

Tags: ios, swift, sinch

I am working on SINCH swift project that I have a screen for video call and I have two views first view is local view and second is remote view. When the user requests a video call the local view (camera of user) should be on fullscreen and remote view hidden until the video call is established. When establish the remote view will be on fullscreen and local view in small size on right side. Any suggestions of how to do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have some code you can share to help others help you?

Comment: I'm trying using storyboard not programmatically ! and i think in this case you need to configure view programmatically not on storyboard !